# Сохранение данных из excel в базу данных

Tags: python, база-данных, excel

Я пытаюсь прочитать excel файл и данные из некоторых столбцов записать в поля модели django.
Я могу получить данные, но они приходят одним списком, в котором более 6000 значений, или же я могу сохранить в кортеж.
Вопрос такой, как мне сделать так, чтобы каждое из этих значений сохранялось в отдельное поле?
Я прочитала про pandas, но не нашла информацию как именно сохранить данные в бд.
Вот что я делаю и что у меня получается.
Я только учусь и буду признательна, если поможете советом, с чем мне ознакомиться

```
wb = load_workbook(filename)
        sheet = wb.active
a = Issue()
a.person = [v[0].value for v in sheet['B5':'B6320']]
```

и в итоге я получаю огромный список.
Пытаюсь с помощью цикла for вытащить значения, но получаю вот такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: из простых вариантов - это [xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/)

Comment: какая у вас БД?

Comment: я использую sqlite, но мне надо чтобы оно так же отрабатывало на postresql